# After installing Pytorch cuda , torch.cuda.is_available() show false. What to do?

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I have installed pytorch cuda by running this command:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

My cuda version is `11.2` . I am using `windows 10` .
Pytorch `cuda 11.2` is not available right now . ([pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/))

So I have install `11.1` version .

(using `nvidia-smi`)
[Cuda version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZoat.png)

But it show false.

```
torch.cuda.is_available() >>> False
```

I have tried both `10.2` and `11.1` version.

As far as I know, I do not need to install cuda toolkit for pytorch

Comment: Are you calling `torch.cuda.is_available()` correctly from the Conda environment you installed into?

Comment: I think , i am calling correctly .

Comment: After looking at your screenshot, you apparently used `nvidia-smi` to check your CUDA version, **but** this command does not give the current CUDA version running. It just prints a compatible version considering your GPU, instead use `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt` or `nvcc --version`

Comment: i am using windows 10.. Your two commands does not work on my system.

Comment: On Windows, you have to find where is located cuda. Once you found it, you should also find a file `version.txt`. A possible way to do so : through powershell `where cudnn*`which should prompt something like this `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\vx.x\bin\cudnn_x.dll\` go back to  `CUDA`\vX.X\` here should be located `version.txt`

Comment: `>>>where cudnn*  >>>>  `  in powershel this command show nothing. @Skaddd

Comment: Your installation image shows you installed cudatoolkit 10.2?

Comment: Ohh sorry ... I have later uninstall the `10.2`  .. and install `11.1`    forget to change the image.

Comment: Try my below instructions

Answer (score 2):

You should not install package to your base environment. Create a separate environment with necessary tools.

Example: create env called dlearn with Python v3.7 and torch packages

```sh
conda create -n dlearn python=3.7 pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

Activate and use your dlearn environment

```sh
conda activate dlearn
python -c "import torch;print(torch.cuda.is_available())"
# this should echo True if all is well
```

At the moment the supported  cudatoolkit is 11.1 which works fine with 11.2 driver. They will update it sooner or later. You can build from GitHub PyTorch to get the latest if you want. The steps are more complex than above.